# Multiple SVGs Get Created Rather Than A Bar Chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my csv data.

```
a,b
1,2
2,4
3,6
4,8
5,10
```

This is my d3.js script.

```
<script>

    d3.csv("data/mydata.csv", function (data) 
    {           
        console.log(data);

        var canvas = d3.select('body')
                        .append('svg')
                        .attr("width", 500)
                        .attr("height", 500);

        var groupA = canvas.append("g");

        var bars = groupA.selectAll('rect')
                     .data(data)
                     .enter()
                     .append('rect')
                     .attr("x", 0)
                     .attr("y", function(d,i){ return i*30;})
                     .attr("width", function(d){ return d.a*40;} )
                     .attr("height", 20);            

    });

</script>
```

What I want is to create a bar chart like this.

[Desired Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhCah.jpg)

I have done this during our lab exercise. However, when I tried to do it again using my laptop, it does not work. So I used inspect element to see if there are problems. It shows that there are 5 SVGs that were created. This shouldn't have happened.

[5 SVGs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFv7G.jpg)

Reading the csv file seems to work fine.

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhWhp.jpg)

I have tried to use Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, and Mozilla Firefox just in case it would be able to produce the desired graph.

I am using Windows 10. However, this shouldn't be an issue as the computer I had used in my lab exercise was also using Windows 10.

Comment: The csv file is not read correctly. you should have, only one object : `Array(5)`. I supected this come from your d3.js version, or your csv enconding

Comment: It worked! Thanks. It seems that the latest version of d3.js (version 5.0.0) caused the problem. When I changed it to version 4, it worked perfectly.